# PHP require/require_once will not work, include will

Tags: php

I have one staging server that stopped running cron jobs. After some research, it turns out that require_once was failing.

I've seen other related questions, and this has nothing to do with paths, absolute or relative. I can create a new file test.php, try to require it in the same folder with the file owner, and fail:

```
php -r 'include("test.php"); echo "hello\n"'
```

hello

```
php -r 'require("test.php"); echo "hello\n"'
```

> PHP Fatal error...failed opening 'test.php'...include path .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php'

Out of desparation, I moved test.php to `/usr/share/pear/test.php`, same error. Also I've tried `./test.php`, `__dir__."/test.php"`, same error.

PHP 5.3.3, which is dated, but working on 2 other servers (dev and prod)

Is it just broken?

Comment: For `php -C` and `php-cli` the *current working directory* is relevant, not if both scripts reside in the same directory. The `__DIR__` constant needs to be written in uppercase, btw.

Comment: That was just me being lazy. It will give the same error (when using __DIR__) but print out the full absolute path to the file.

Comment: Are you sure `include` really is working? If it fails opening in include, it won't be a fatal error like it would with require, and might not show up depending on your error reporting settings.

Comment: Ok, whatever. It's somewhat unlikely that your PHP interpreter suddenly stopped working. It's almost guaranteed that it's some form of path/permission mishap. Even with heaps of additional info (ls -l, dir struct., distro, phpinfo, …) this is unlikely to be answerable without direct access to your server. Just let someone else look it over. (If you really want to debug it, use DBG or `strace` for some introspection.)

Comment: Good call. I put output into test.php, and it isn't showing up, so no, include is not working either.

Comment: Well I think that just leaves the more obvious permission issues. Right?

Comment: echo `whoami` -> cdstaging
pwd -> /home/cdstaging
ll test.php -> -rwxrwxr-x 1 cdstaging cdstaging ... test.php
strace php run.php -> ...lstat("/home/cdstaging/test.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0775, st_size=43, ...}) = 0

Fatal error

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone's help. I wanted to post the solution.

Someone altered the php.ini file and set the open_basedir (to a fairly useless directory I might add), which essentially limited php functionality to that directory. Unfortunately this doesn't throw any useful error.

Thanks again!